# How can I add an ADC sensor on STM32WL pre-application?

Tags: stm32, c

I am trying to read ADC values from a microphone. I am using the FFT to get 100 Hz to 2 kHz or more to detect tones. In my project, I can use DMA to get ADC values and then I use DSP CMSIS. I can do this with my new workspace (without anything only ADC-DMA) but when I try to implement it together with the  PingPong application [githubpingpong](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeWL/tree/main/Projects/NUCLEO-WL55JC/Applications/SubGHz_Phy/SubGHz_Phy_PingPong) I am struggling. I am an STM32 beginner and I can't find any video or blog about adding ADC sensors on the STM32WL.

As I say, I did a lot of things but I can't add ADC polling or ADC DMA method to the PingPong application. I tried to add adc_if.c, adc_if.h, sys_app.c, sys_app.h but I couldn't manage it.

I found adc.c and I configure it for poll method, I only made continous cov mode enable.

`hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;`

and other files (adc.c etc.) I tried to add these.  I am using IN0 of ADC. So it is ADC_CHANNEL_0:

```
static uint32_t ADC_ReadMicData(uint32_t channel)
{
 uint32_t ADCxConvertedValues = 0;
 ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
 MX_ADC_Init();
 /* Configure Regular Channel */
 sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
 sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
 sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_COMMON_1;
 if (HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
 {
  /* Start Error */
  Error_Handler();
 }
 /** Wait for end of conversion */
 HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
 /** Wait for end of conversion */
 ADCxConvertedValues = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
 return ADCxConvertedValues;
 /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_ReadChannels_2 */
 /* USER CODE END ADC_ReadChannels_2 */
 
}
```

I added my I2C sensor on my own, but I couldn't find ADC for my microphone.

Can you tell me how to add an ADC sensor for to the PingPong application? If there is a video or something can you share with me please?

Comment: I found the problem, truns out some how they inactive ADC_CHANNEL_0 and ADC_CHANNEL_1 in this appliication. I change it to ADC_CHANNEL_3 and it works.